# i can't close the alert form MUI using the crossIcon

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

I have a snackBar and inside an alert both from MUI. The issue is that I want to close the alert using a function and when clicking on the crossIcon, close it. I don't know why it's not working as I'm using the most of the code from MUI example.
Any idea? I'm new to react and MUI.

[image]

```
import { useState } from 'react';

import CloseIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Close';
import { Alert, AlertTitle, IconButton, Snackbar, Typography } from '@mui/material';

interface InfoMessageProps {
  open: boolean;
}

export const InfoMessage = ({ open }: InfoMessageProps) => {
  const [openMessage, setOpenMesage] = useState(false);

  // const handleClose = (_event?: Event | React.SyntheticEvent, reason?: string) => {
  //   if (reason === 'clickaway') {
  //     return;
  //   }
  //   setOpenMesage(false);
  // };


const handleCloseMessage = (): void => {
  setOpenMesage(false);
  console.log(handleCloseMessage);
};

  return (
    <Snackbar
      open={open}
      autoHideDuration={4000}
      anchorOrigin={{ vertical: 'top', horizontal: 'right' }}
      onClose={handleCloseMessage}
    >
      <Alert
        sx={{
              width: '487px',
              height: '104px',
              paddingTop: '20px',
              paddingLeft: '20px',
              backgroundColor: '#FDFDFD',
        }}
        icon={false}
        action={(
          <IconButton
            aria-label="close"
            color="inherit"
            size="small"
            onClick={handleCloseMessage}
          >
            <CloseIcon fontSize="inherit" />
          </IconButton>
        )}
      >
        <AlertTitle sx={{ paddingRight:'80px' }}>
          <Typography variant='headings.h4'>title</Typography>
        </AlertTitle>
        <Typography variant='captions.default'>Insert message here</Typography>
      </Alert>
    </Snackbar>
  );
};
```

Comment: I'd start by inspecting the crossicon element using your browser dev tools, selecting it via right-click - and verify you actually land on that element in the DOM inspector then, and that there is not perhaps some other transparent element on top of it which would "catch" the click event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Snackbar` is open due to the `open` prop. You're not changing this state inside the `InfoMessage` component. You could pass a callback from you parent component to the `InfoMessage` and update the state.

```js
function ParentComponent() {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(true);

  return (
    <div>
      <InfoMessage open={open} onClose={() => setOpen(false)} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

And then you can use that callback in your `InfoMessage` component.

```js
interface InfoMessageProps {
  open: boolean;
  onClose: () => void;
}

export const InfoMessage = ({ open, onClose }: InfoMessageProps) => {
  const [openMessage, setOpenMesage] = useState(false);

  return (
    <Snackbar
      open={open}
      autoHideDuration={4000}
      anchorOrigin={{ vertical: "top", horizontal: "right" }}
      onClose={onClose}
    >
      <Alert
        sx={{
          width: "487px",
          height: "104px",
          paddingTop: "20px",
          paddingLeft: "20px",
          backgroundColor: "#FDFDFD",
        }}
        icon={false}
        action={
          <IconButton
            aria-label="close"
            color="inherit"
            size="small"
            onClick={onClose}
          >
            <CloseIcon fontSize="inherit" />
          </IconButton>
        }
      >
        <AlertTitle sx={{ paddingRight: "80px" }}>
          <Typography variant="headings.h4">title</Typography>
        </AlertTitle>
        <Typography variant="captions.default">Insert message here</Typography>
      </Alert>
    </Snackbar>
  );
};
```

Comment: My partent component has this: <Button
            onClick={(): void => void setShowInfo(true)}
          >
            open info message
          </Button>
          <InfoMessage open={showInfo} onClose={(): void => void setShowInfo(false)} />

Comment: and my component InfoMessage has the code that you've just told me to include, but still not closing the message with the cross icon. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: I've made a [working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-dust-tbptwu), your code seems like it should work @mariadev

Answer (score 1):

```js
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Alert, AlertTitle, Fade } from "@mui/material";

export default function AlertBox() {

  const [alertVisibility, setAlertVisibility] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setAlertVisibility(false);
    }, 3000);
  });

  return (
    <Fade in={alertVisibility} timeout={{ exit: 1000 }}>
      <Alert
        onClose={() => {
          setAlertVisibility(false);
        }}
        severity="success"
        variant="filled"
        sx={{
          minWidth: 300,
          position: "absolute",
          zIndex: 100,
          bottom: 10,
          right: 10,
        }}
      >
        <AlertTitle>Warning</AlertTitle>
        Message here
      </Alert>
    </Fade>
  );
};
```

Comment: You could improve your answer by adding a description of what the code snippet does, what the problem was, how you found it and how you solved it.